# JNI GetEnv() returns null in JNI_OnLoad

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

For some reason, when I call `GetEnv()`, it returns NULL.
I know that this is a normal behaviour when calling it from a thread that in not attached to the VM object but, in my case, I'm calling it from `JNI_OnLoad`, which is called when I call `System.loadLibrary` on the JAVA, should it shoult not be NULL.

JNI.h :

```
class JNI
{
public:

    static jint OnLoad( JavaVM * pJavaVM, void * reserved );

    static JNIEnv * GetEnv();

    // Etc...
};
```

JNI.cpp :

```
jint JNI::OnLoad( JavaVM * pJavaVM, void * reserved )
{
    static bool bFirstCall = true;

    if( ! bFirstCall )
    {
        LOGCAT_E( "Tnx::JNI::OnLoad() - Cannot call this function more than once." );
        return -1;
    }

    bFirstCall = false;

    LOGCAT_I( "Tnx::JNI::OnLoad() - Begin, pJavaVM = %p.", pJavaVM );

    s_pJavaVM = pJavaVM;

    try
    {
        JNIEnv * pEnv = GetEnv(); // THROWS HERE

        // More stuff...
    }
    catch( const exception & oExc )
    {
        LOGCAT_E( "Tnx::JNI::OnLoad() - Failed, exception : '%s'.", oExc.what() );
        return false;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        LOGCAT_E( "Tnx::JNI::OnLoad() - Failed, unknown exception." );
        return false;
    }

    LOGCAT_I( "Tnx::JNI::OnLoad() - End, success." );
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}

JNIEnv * JNI::GetEnv()
{
    JNIEnv * const pEnv = NULL;

    if( NULL == s_pJavaVM )
        throw runtime_error( "Tnx::JNI::GetEnv() - s_pJavaVM is NULL." );

    s_pJavaVM->GetEnv( (void **) & pEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_4 );

    if( NULL == pEnv )
        throw runtime_error( "Tnx::JNI::GetEnv() - Failed to get JNI environment." );

    return pEnv;
}

jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad( JavaVM * pJavaVM, void * reserved )
{
    return Tnx::JNI::OnLoad( pJavaVM, reserved );
}
```

.java :

```
public class XXXXActivity extends Activity
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary( "XXXXNative" );
    }

    private native static boolean initializeNative( XXXXActivity XXXXActivity, TermScreenView termScreenView );

    private native static boolean finalizeNative();

    private native boolean initializeInstance();

    private native boolean finalizeInstance();

    private TermScreenView mTermScreenView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        Log.v( "", "XXXXActivity#onCreate() - Begin." );

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        try
        {
            this.setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );

            setContentView( R.layout.activity_XXXX );
            mTermScreenView = (TermScreenView) findViewById( R.id.termScreenView );
        }
        catch( Exception exc )
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        if( null == savedInstanceState )
        {
            Log.v( "", "XXXXActivity#onCreate() - First call to onCreate, initializing native layer." );

            if( ! (initializeNative( this, mTermScreenView ) && initializeInstance()) )
                Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), "Failed to initialize", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

        Log.v( "", "XXXXActivity#onCreate() - End." );
    }

    // Etc...
}
```

Log :

```
10-01 13:07:14.460: D/dalvikvm(29694): Trying to load lib /data/data/XXXX.XXXX/lib/libXXXXNative.so 0x41970d10
10-01 13:07:14.460: D/dalvikvm(29694): Added shared lib /data/data/XXXX.XXXX/lib/libXXXXNative.so 0x41970d10
10-01 13:07:14.463: I/XXXX.XXXX(29694): Tnx::JNI::OnLoad() - Begin, pJavaVM = 0x40f34948.
10-01 13:07:14.463: E/XXXX.XXXX(29694): Tnx::JNI::OnLoad() - Failed, exception : 'Tnx::JNI::GetEnv() - Failed to get JNI environment.'.
10-01 13:07:14.463: W/dalvikvm(29694): JNI_OnLoad returned bad version (0) in /data/data/XXXX.XXXX/lib/libXXXXNative.so 0x41970d10
10-01 13:07:15.123: D/dalvikvm(29694): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

Any idea why it could be NULL ? Thanks.

Comment: You should check the return value from `GetEnv`. It could be that `JNI_VERSION_1_4` isn't supported, in which case `GetEnv` will return `JNI_EVERSION`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Might have been that, but it worked before with the same NDK, same SDK, same eclipse version, same JNI version, same everything. I'm only having this problem since i did some big changes in the code. Still gonna check this just in case.

Comment: @Michael Well it's returning JNI_OK :(

Comment: You've declared `pEnv` as a const pointer. I don't see why you'd want to do that if you intend to let `GetEnv` change the value of `pEnv`(?).

Comment: Yeah the const isn't supposed to be here, i just didn't notice it. I'm still getting the problem after removing the const though. :( I also tried changing to JNI  1.6, but same behaviour.

Comment: @Michael I moved the code from JNI::GetEnv() to JNI_OnLoad and for some reason i'm getting a non-null pointer. Maybe that fact of having this code inside a class is causing a problem.

Comment: Well for some reason it works now. Not sure why. Maybe was it the const after all. EDIT : After testing, indeed it was the const, for some dark reason. If you make this answer i'll validate it. Thanks for the help.